# ERROR: Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError in android application which is live

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps, api-key

accidentally I just removed my Google Map API key from the API-Console and now it shows me an error in the application of `Oops Something Went Wrong`.

**Is it possible to fix this in the live application or maybe get the same key again from Google-Map API console?**

If yes then **How can I fix it in my application?** Well my application is live on Google playstore too.

Comment: When did you delete an API key? If it wasn't a long time ago you can try to file a support case in Google Cloud developer console: https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support. Hopefully, Google can help to recover an API key.

Comment: When did you delete an API key? If it wasn't a long time ago you can try to file a support case in Google Cloud developer console: https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support. Hopefully, Google can help to recover an API key.

Comment: @xomena I tried but still getting the same error